# Address bar still visible even with digital asset link

Tags: trusted-web-activity

We have a PWA hosted at [www.thredup.com](http://www.thredup.com) that is published as a TWA in the Play Store for closed testing. The digital asset link is OK but the address bar is still visible in the TWA.

Is there something wrong with the digital asset link that would prevent the address bar from hiding? Do we need to do something else to hide the address bar other than setting up the digital asset link?

The digital asset link for the TWA (package com.thredup.www.twa) is available at [www.thredup.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json](http://www.thredup.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json).

```
{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.thredup.www.twa",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["B5:B4:0C:36:87:C1:1B:74:02:90:18:14:D8:52:F9:45:62:81:BC:F4:A1:AD:23:07:66:3E:2D:A0:06:10:99:1D"]
  }
}
```

We're using the SHA 256 of the Google App signing key (not the upload key) for the Play Store listing in the digital asset link.

The Asset Links Tool app on Android shows the same digital asset link for the com.thredup.www.twa package when TWA is installed on device.

Testing the app linking using the [Statement List Generator and Tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator) validates host [www.thredup.com](http://www.thredup.com) is granting app deep linking to com.thredup.www.twa.

The only way I found to hide the TWA address bar is to disable the digital asset link verification for [www.thredup.com](http://www.thredup.com) url using Chrome command line as described here: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa#enabling-debug

Comment: Did you find any solutions, me also facing the same issue very recently., but initially it worked!

Comment: @RavikumarRajendran, if you already confirmed the Asset Link Tool like andreban suggested, try recreate your TWA with https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/tree/main/packages/cli.
My old TWA was showing the bar, and it hides after recreate.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend running [Peter's Asset Link Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.conn.assetlinkstool) on the application installed **from the Play Store**. It will give you the correct Asset Links file (which you can compare to the one currently being used).

Comment: Thank your for the reply. I already ran the asset link tool app per my initial post. Here's [a screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/VtDRcxf/1668528174924.jpg) of what this tool shows. You can see that it's using the same digital asset link as the one provided on www.thredup.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: I have quite a result, It was already worked and is now broken for us. the sha256_cert_fingerprints are different from the one peter's tool generated and the one which is located on the site. Any idea how sha256_cert_fingerprints  could change?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever upload assetlinks.json with upload key(old key) and install apk?
Then the chrome browser will save old key in cache.
So you can try to install again after clear cache of chrome.